# Sufficient conditions to ensure the existence of a point $c$ such that $f'(c)=f(c)$ for $f\in \mathscr{C}^1([0, 1])$

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity

I'm not able to solve this exercise:

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a strictly positive function, derivable with continuous derivative, such that $f(0) = 1 $.
Show that $\exists c\in[0,1] $ such that $f'(c)=f(c)$ if at least one of the following conditions holds:
a) $f(1)=e$
b) $f(1)>e$ and $f$ has some extreme point in (0,1).
Show that the two conditions of b), taken singularly, are not sufficient to imply the claim.

My idea to show that a) implies the claim was to apply some theorem to the continuous function $F(x):= f(x)-f'(x)$ but I'm not sure which one.
For b) I don't even know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
Consider the function $g(x) = e^{-x} f(x)$.

---

**Full answer**

For $x\in [0,1]$, let :
$$g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$$
Then $g$ is a positive function, derivable with continuous derivative and :
$$\forall x \in [0,1], g'(x) =e^{-x}(f'(x) - f(x))$$

Therefore, we are looking for $c\in [0,1]$ such that $g'(c) = 0$.

a) Assume $f(1) = e$. Then, $g(1) = f(1) = 1$ so by Rolle's theorem there is such  a $c\in (0,1)$.

b) Assume $f(1) >e $ and there is $a\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(a) = 0$. Then $g(1) > g(0) = 1$ and $g'(a) = -e^{-a} f(a) < 0$. By the mean value theorem, there is $b\in (0,1)$ such that $g'(b) = g(1)-g(0) >0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is $c \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c) = 0$.

Comment: ok, understood everything, I guess in the second line of $b)$ it should be $f(a)$ instead of $f(b)$.